# Trying to properly organize huge class

Tags: c#, .net

I have huge class that implements usage of some client:

```
public class Client : IClient
{
   internal Client(string username, string password){
   //login process here
   }
   //some private methods that make sure connection stays alive, etc
   public void Action1(string param1){
   //something here...
   }
   public void Action2(string param1, string param2){
   //something else here...
   }
}
```

As it currently is, it's 5000+ lines long mainly because of lots of different public methods.
I'm wondering what is the best practice to properly organize and refactor this, preferably without making method calls more complicated?

Comment: sometime a class has a lot of code, its not inherently wrong. But its hard to say if your class is well designed without having waaaay more details

Comment: OOP will solve it ;)

Comment: Consider at least splitting it into multiple files using partial classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use partial classes and group things into logical sets per each partial class.

Also, if some methods make logical set, consider wrapping them into separate class.

Those 2 should reduce your lines of code per file dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

Usually big class are "hiding" inside other classes (see uncle Bob on "Clean Code").

In your case I'd split the class creating Action classes and making some machanics that lets the Client use some sort of IAction or BaseAction. Thus splitting the logic of every action into a separate class.

To be more precise I'd rather need some more info and code.